# Sagnac effect and interval invariance

Tags: special-relativity, coordinate-systems, rotational-kinematics

In [this](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/320759081_The_Sagnac_effect_and_its_interpretation_by_Paul_Langevin) article there is one thing I don't get: the author considers (page 9) transformation of the coordinates $$(t,r,\theta)\mapsto (t,r,\theta+\omega t)$$ and then apparently uses invariance of the interval, but it is preserved, whenever we go from one inertial frame to another... However, don't we move to the non-inertial frame, since it is rotating?

Maybe it works this way, since we rotate not only our space, but also "rotate" the metric too (we work with $ds^2 = c^2dt^2 - dr^2 - r^2d\theta^2$)?

Answer (score 1):

For discussion of the Sagnac effect I recommend the 2004 article by Olaf Wucknitz

[Sagnac effect, twin paradox and space-time topology - Time and length in rotating systems and closed Minkowski space-times](https://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/0403111)

Olaf Wucknitz discusses (among other things) the case of a circular perimeter, in rotating motion. Wucknits argues: the acceleration is perpendicular to the circumnavigating motion. Because of that the circumnavigating velocity can be treated as inertial motion. Wucknitz argues that the perimeter can be thought of as a Minkowski spacetime with 1 spatial dimension (and the time dimension, of course). Crucially: this perimeter has a *loop topology*. It is a space wich a *single* spatial dimension, *and* the space loops back onto itself.

Wucknitz argues: this perimeter is a *closed spacetime*. With a *loop topology* a synchonizing signal can loop around. That has ramifications for synchronization.

Of all the material about the Sagnac effect that I encountered I consider the article by Olaf Wucknitz to be the best, by far.

Answer (score 0):

There is a common interpretational problen in the orininal question. The interval is indeed conserved when passing to a noninertial frame. If that were not true general relativity would be impossible.